# Delete node xml by using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to delete node with condition if status in telephone does not equal 'A'

This is my xml

```
<name>
    <name>
        <firstName>Yuio</firstName>
        <lastName>Kuyoshitu</lastName>
        <telephoneNav>
            <detail>
                <action>A</action>
                <number>1745</number>
            </detail>
            <detail>
                <action>P</action>
                <number>1189</number>
            </detail>
        </telephoneNav>
    </name>
    <name>
        <firstName>Huio</firstName>
        <lastName>Kuyoshitu</lastName>
        <telephoneNav>
            <detail>
                <action>P</action>
                <number>0902</number>
            </detail>
            <detail>
                <action>P</action>
                <number>0901</number>
            </detail>
        </telephoneNav>
    </name>
</name>
```

If name node does not have telephone number with `A` status. I want to delete name node

This is expected result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><name>
<name>
    <firstName>Yuio</firstName>
    <lastName>Kuyoshitu</lastName>
    <telephoneNav>
       <detail>
            <action>A</action>
            <number>1745</number>
        </detail>
    </telephoneNav>
</name>
```

I try to this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/name/name/telephoneNav/detail[not(action = 'A')]"/>
  <xsl:template match="/name/name/telephoneNav/text()[not(normalize-space())]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I still got name node with empty `telephoneNav`

This is my result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><name>
    <name>
        <firstName>Yuio</firstName>
        <lastName>Kuyoshitu</lastName>
        <telephoneNav>
           <detail>
                <action>A</action>
                <number>1745</number>
            </detail>
        </telephoneNav>
    </name>
    <name>
        <firstName>Huio</firstName>
        <lastName>Kuyoshitu</lastName>
        <telephoneNav />
    </name>
</name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If name node does not have telephone number with A status. I want to delete name node

For this, you can do:

```
<xsl:template match="/name/name[not(telephoneNav/detail/action = 'A')]"/>
```

But it seems you also want to remove `detail` nodes that do not have an `A` action. This can be done using:

```
<xsl:template match="detail[not(action = 'A')]"/>
```